# problem with localization in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, localization, internationalization, xib

I have a German program written in objective C for iPhone.
I want localize it to English, so in a file.xib I clicked on + to add localization, English appears, then I insert German.
Running the app with iphone in English goes ok, if i change language it crashes.

I've tried clean-rebuild and check folders but i get this error

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'MainWindow''

Comment: @Pawel I guess it's `How to prevent it from crashing` *facepalm*

Comment: @fluchtpunkt, that is what I am guessing as well. The problem is, it is not obvious from original question (which I edited to make more clear).

Comment: yes...the question is how can i solve it. If i localize a xib for example in italian, then i set italian from iphone menu, it crashes with that error, if i put another language all ok

Comment: same problem here. I design my app for the english language but now I have the same problem as yours but only the french language is working with me -,.- and its not in the MainWindow but from other xib.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the hell was happening, but I solved the problem by removing the original MainWindow.xib and adding a new one, which was not related to any localization.

Grrrr!